# media query in css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How do I write media query only for 1024px width?

Here is my existing css which i have written for 320px width and more

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {

}
```

What is the method for only 1024px width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    /* styles for width > 320px but < 1023px */
}


@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 /* styles for width > 1024px only */
}
```

this way you do not have to override any styles.

otherwise you can do that:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    /* styles for width > 320px - applied to width > 1024px too */
}


@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 /* styles for width > 1024px only */
}
```

that is different in the way that you will have to override your first media query styles when needeed, in the second one

Comment: My design is different for 1024px and more than tat size so if i write your code for 1024px then what can be written for more than 1024px?

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your comment, I hope I've understood well what you are asking for!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you *just* want 1024, not 1023 or less, or 1025 or more, you could do

```
@media (width: 1024px) {
    ....
 }
```

The min/max prefixes are optional. [See the w3 entry on it](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width).

Comment: "What is the method for only 1024px width?" if you want to set styling for ONLY 1024px viewports, then this is the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
@media (max-width:1024px) {
 body{..}

}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/YhsSK/