# Site with Two Different Headers

Tags: html, css, header

I have a website that has a home page header, and a header on the rest of the pages on a site.

I no longer like the responsiveness of the home page header, and want to replace it with the header on the other pages.

Is there anyway in the HTML of my site to dictate the use of one header when the site is >1050px, and another when the site is <=1050px?

Thank you in advance.

This is slightly different than the [media query in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050633/media-query-in-css) question, but i was wanting to use more HTML as the links are going to be different when it goes below 1050px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [media query in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050633/media-query-in-css)

Comment: @nkorth if you want to tag a question for a possible duplicate at least tag a copy of something that answers his question otherwise it is not helping anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will do something like this first hide your second header

```
#header-2{display: none}
```

To do the switch at 1050px do this

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1050px){
    #header-1{display: none;}
    #header-2{display: inline}
}
```

This should do it for you, if you supply some code I can put in the actual values for you.

Comment: This would be done using CSS only, there is not something that I can do using HTML?

Comment: No, you can do it many different ways. But you cannot do it purely in HTML. You can put it right in your html if you use the `<style>` tags though

Comment: Ok. This doesn't sound like it is going to be fun or easy... Let me take a stab at it and I will get back to you and let you know the results! Thank you for getting back to me!

Comment: Yes, each are in their own embed code. `{embed="embeds/.homeheader"}` vs `{embed="embeds/.header"}`

Comment: If you want to update your question with your html I will write the css for you.